Android Fragment: EditText setOnFocusChangeListener
The situation I am struggling with:
One MainActivity and four fragments... ...in a nutshell how to set a lost foccus event on a given EditText field contained on a Fragment?
In a simple activity this works very well.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
oET_PSN = findViewById(R.id.txtEqPSN);

oET_PSN.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
       if(!hasFocus){

             Log.d("oET_PSN", "Lost Focus");
            
          }
      }
 })

....
....
But how to get this to work in a Fragment?
Various youtubes; Various stackoverflow posts... ...I am looking for a simple example that can easily be replicated

The solution to my question is as follows:  (Hope it helps someone)
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_build, container, false);

    oET_PSN = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.txtEqPSN);
    oET_DESC = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.txtEqPSNDescription);

    oET_PSN.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                Log.d("LUCK", "Lost Focus");
                //call function on getPSNDescription method created in main activity and set the text on the EditText in Fragment 
                oET_DESC.setText ( ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPSNDescription("BuildFragment",oET_PSN.getText().toString()) );


            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}


I guess you are doing this on onCreate() of the fragment.
To ensure the EditText where you are adding this needs to be sure that if the View is getting inflated on the screen before you add any listener or do any kind of operation.
Incase of fragments, the lifecycle events are bit different. onCreateView() is the place where the view gets initialized/laid on the screen.
So doing any operation after its inflation will work perfectly fine.
Its advised to add any operation/state management inside onViewCreated(). This ensures view has been created and you can do any operation you want.
Hope this helps.
I would recommend to go through basics of activity and fragment lifecycle in depth.
references:
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle
https://deeandroid.medium.com/exploring-the-fragment-lifecycle-in-android-a-comprehensive-guide-to-add-and-replace-methods-and-44eeed3d4da4
If you like the solution, give a thumbs up.
Thanks!
